# How create dataframe from list of dictionary of multi level json

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

So I have a json file that have multiple level,by using pandas I can read the first level and put it in a dataframe,but the problem is as you can see in the dataframe [Column Comments and hastags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgp1H.jpg) the second level is inside a column have format of list of dictionary,is there any solution for make the second level dictionary into dataframe. I try to use for loop and `json_normalize` but it always throw an error. Any suggestion? My code is like this

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.read_json("data.json")

cid = []
for x in df2["comments"]:
    cid.append(x.get('cid'))


data = pd.DataFrame({'cid':cid})
```

If i use the code it throw an error since I try access list by `string` not `index`.

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Even I change it into integer it got dictionary inside a column.How to change the dict inside the column or is there another easier way to do this? [Dictionary in column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTHnh.jpg)

```
for x in df2["comments"]:
    cid.append(x[0])
data = pd.DataFrame({'cid':cid})
for y in data:
    print(y.get('cid'))
```

Example of first row of the data frame

```
[{'cid': '7000061798167266075', 'createTime': 1629828926, 'text': 'Done ', 'diggCount': 1, 'replyCommentTotal': 0, 'uid': '6529379534374092801', 'uniqueId': 'alikayanti'}, {'cid': '6999869922566783771', 'createTime': 1629784228, 'text': 'haloo min, yg udah ikutan di misi sebelumnya boleh ikutan lagi gaa?', 'diggCount': 1, 'replyCommentTotal': 1, 'uid': '6842932775562642433', 'uniqueId': 'fia_654'}, {'cid': '7000248857603588891', 'createTime': 1629872457, 'text': 'bell bottoms maksudnya apa kak?\napakah benar artinya bel bawah?', 'diggCount': 0, 'replyCommentTotal': 2, 'uid': '6960940768727417857', 'uniqueId': 'keterimadiptn1'}, {'cid': '7000322023545455387', 'createTime': 1629889491, 'text': 'syudah', 'diggCount': 0, 'replyCommentTotal': 0, 'uid': '6806645499672839170', 'uniqueId': 'miftahulhaqqu'}, {'cid': '7001271117180977947', 'createTime': 1630110475, 'text': 'kak, perpanjang dong waktu posting videonya :)', 'diggCount': 1, 'replyCommentTotal': 0, 'uid': '6921267441846830082', 'uniqueId': 'elisabetkst'}]
```

Comment: `x[0]` is `[{item},{...}]` according to this ... so maybe `x[0][0].get('cid')` ... i think really we dont have enough info to help you with this as it stands

Comment: You can take the first row of your dataframe and convert it to another dataframe using `pd.DataFrame(cid)`.

Comment: The question here is ambiguous. You want the cid value from the comments column as a value, but there is more than one cid value, and it is not clear which one you want. We need more info to provide a useful answer.

Comment: @NickODell so what i want is actually taking every single the cid value and transform into a single column

Comment: I also cannot use ```print(df2["comments"]["cid"])``` since it will raise an error of ```keyerror:'cid'``` because when we ``print(df2["comments"][:0])``` it gave a result of ```[{'cid': '7060401706874012442'}]``` is there way to access the cid and transform into a column. I am confused because it saved in list of dict

Comment: FYI, lack of a [mcve] might result in waste of time for both parties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution is through multiple for loop after we looping the row of the targeted column,and after that append it as a list

```
unique_id = []
cid = []
createTime = []
text = []
diggCount = []
replyCommentTotal = []
uid = []


for items in df2["comments"]:
    for x in items:
        unique_id.append(x["uniqueId"])
        cid.append(x["cid"])
        createTime.append(x["createTime"])
        text.append(x["text"])
        diggCount.append(x["diggCount"])
        replyCommentTotal.append(x["replyCommentTotal"])
        uid.append(x["uid"])

data = pd.DataFrame({'unique_id':unique_id,
                     'cid':cid,
                    'createTime':createTime,
                    'text':text,
                    'diggCount':diggCount,
                    'replyCommentTotal':replyCommentTotal,
                    'uid':uid})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solves your problem:

Defined the following function which unnests any json:

```
import json
import pandas as pd


def flatten_nested_json_df(df):
    df = df.reset_index()
    s = (df.applymap(type) == list).all()
    list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
    
    s = (df.applymap(type) == dict).all()
    dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

    
    while len(list_columns) > 0 or len(dict_columns) > 0:
        new_columns = []

        for col in dict_columns:
            horiz_exploded = pd.json_normalize(df[col]).add_prefix(f'{col}.')
            horiz_exploded.index = df.index
            df = pd.concat([df, horiz_exploded], axis=1).drop(columns=[col])
            new_columns.extend(horiz_exploded.columns) # inplace

        for col in list_columns:
            #print(f"exploding: {col}")
            df = df.drop(columns=[col]).join(df[col].explode().to_frame())
            new_columns.append(col)

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == list).all()
        list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == dict).all()
        dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
    return df
```

and do this:

```
results = pd.json_normalize(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(results)

outdf = flatten_nested_json_df(df)
```

which returns:

```
index                  cid  createTime  \
0      0  7000061798167266075  1629828926   
1      1  6999869922566783771  1629784228   
2      2  7000248857603588891  1629872457   
3      3  7000322023545455387  1629889491   
4      4  7001271117180977947  1630110475   

                                                text  diggCount  \
0                                             Done           1   
1  haloo min, yg udah ikutan di misi sebelumnya b...          1   
2  bell bottoms maksudnya apa kak?\napakah benar ...          0   
3                                            syudah          0   
4     kak, perpanjang dong waktu posting videonya :)          1   

   replyCommentTotal                  uid        uniqueId  
0                  0  6529379534374092801      alikayanti  
1                  1  6842932775562642433         fia_654  
2                  2  6960940768727417857  keterimadiptn1  
3                  0  6806645499672839170   miftahulhaqqu  
4                  0  6921267441846830082     elisabetkst
```